# How to do a sql to get data from a table like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

From the table below, how could I possibly get data out like this:
My sql knowledge is limited to select and other basic stuff.

```
Heading 1 Eg: Kitchenware
 Heading 2 Eg: Knives
  Heading 3 Eg: Butter Knives
   Item: Cut em all
   Item: Cull em all
   Item: Smear em all 
  Heading 3 Eg: Meat Knives
   Item: Cut em meat
   Item: Cull em meat
   Item: Smear em meat
```

Levels 1 and 2 are headings and cannot hold items. Level 3 can hold items. Level 4 are items. Will it be possible to do the above. Sometimes, Level 3 may come after Level 1.

```
"id"    "name"         "description"               "level"  "parent"    "country"   "maxLevel"
"1"     "Kitchenware"   "Kitchenware description"   "1"       "0"         "US"        "0"
"2"     "Knives"        "All our knives"            "2"       "1"         "US"        "0"
"3"     "Butter Knives" "All Butter Knives"         "3"       "2"         "US"        "0"
"4"     "Cut em all"    "Cut em all"                "4"       "3"         "US"        "0"
"5"     "Cull em all"   "Cull em all"               "4"       "3"         "US"        "0"
"6"     "Smear em all"  "Smear em all"              "4"       "3"         "US"        "0"
"7"     "Meat Knives"   "All Meat Knives"           "3"       "2"         "US"        "0"
"8"     "Cut em meat"   "Cut em meat"               "4"       "7"         "US"        "0"
"9"     "Cull em meat"  "Cull em meat"              "4"       "7"         "US"        "0"
"10"    "Smear em meat" "Smear em meat"             "4"       "7"         "US"        "0"
```

**Table create**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` INT(10) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(240) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `level` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `parent` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `country` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `maxLevel` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**Table Data**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `type`, `parent`, `country`, `maxLevel`) VALUES
    (1, 'Kitchenware', 'Kitchenware description', 1, 0, 'US', 0),
    (2, 'Knives', 'All our knives', 2, 1, 'US', 0),
    (3, 'Butter Knives', 'All Butter Knives', 3, 2, 'US', 0),
    (4, 'Cut em all', 'Cut em all', 4, 3, 'US', 0),
    (5, 'Cull em all', 'Cull em all', 4, 3, 'US', 0),
    (6, 'Smear em all', 'Smear em all', 4, 3, 'US', 0),
    (7, 'Meat Knives', 'All Meat Knives', 3, 2, 'US', 0),
    (8, 'Cut em meat', 'Cut em meat', 4, 7, 'US', 0),
    (9, 'Cull em meat', 'Cull em meat', 4, 7, 'US', 0),
    (10, 'Smear em meat', 'Smear em meat', 4, 7, 'US', 0);
```

Comment: See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Barmar I've been working with this and the above article since morning, and then posted here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building a hieraric tree you have to use server coding like PHP.
An alternative for displaying is to build indentation chars based on record level.

Comment: This is _technically_ correct as SQL always returns tables with the same number of rows and no hierarchy information, although it can order the data in a useful way as shown by Tall boY. I'm going to +1 as I don't think this deserves the downvote

Comment: So you say I cant get it all in one statement and that i need several sql statements to do this?

Comment: In MySQL u can get it either with "stored procedures" or with implementing server code. I think you have to build this with recursive functions and this is not supported for a SQL-Statement.
In server code i would built a hieraric array based on the result of getting all records.

Comment: In this case the main problem is you dont know the depth of the hieraric tree, unless either this is fix or you have another table with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a table like this

```
H1                     H2                 H3            Item:
Kitchenware          Knives            Butter Knives   Cut em all
Kitchenware          Knives            Meat Knives     Cut em all
Kitchenware          Knives            Butter Knives   Smear em meat
```

then you can easily select based on `h1 or h2 or h3`

And table structure something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` INT(10) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`h1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`h2` VARCHAR(240) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`h3` VARCHAR(240) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Item:` VARCHAR(240) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`level` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`parent` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`country` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`maxLevel` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

SQl something like `SELECT from table WHERE h1=somthing AND h3=somthing`

Comment: umm... cant change the table, have to stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this. Not the best, but works. They say calling a function from inside a function isn't a good idea.

```
<?php

$conn = connect();

$what = 1;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id as id, name as name, description as description from products where level = :what and country = 'US'");
$stmt->bindParam(':what', $what);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->rowCount();

//echo 'Rows found '.$rows.' hey<br>';

while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{  
    echo $row['name']." ".$row['id'];
    echo "<br><br>";

    $next = $conn->prepare("select id as id, level as level, name as name, description as description from products where level > :what and country = 'US' and parent = :parent");
    $next->bindParam(':what', $row['id']);
    $next->bindParam(':parent', $row['id']);
    $next->execute();

    while($row = $next->fetch())
    {  
        if($row['level'] == '2')
        {
            echo $row['name']." Id: ".$row['id']." Level: ".$row['level']."<br>";
            fetchElements($row['level'],$row['id']);
        }else if($row['level'] == '3')
        {
            echo $row['name']." Id: ".$row['id']." Level: ".$row['level']."<br>";
            fetchElements($row['level'],$row['id']);
        }
    }
}

function fetchElements($one,$two)
{   
    global $conn; //I feel this is incorrect. $conn is defined up there once.
    $elements = $conn->prepare("select id as id, level as level, name as name, description as description from products where level > :what and parent = :parent and country = 'US'");
    $elements->bindParam(':what', $one);
    $elements->bindParam(':parent', $two);
    $elements->execute();

    while($row = $elements->fetch())
    {  
        echo $row['name']." Id: ".$row['id']." Level: ".$row['level']."<br>";
        if($one == 2)
        {
            fetchElements($row['level'],$row['id']);
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```